# Error "not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Tags: python

```
name = raw_input("What is your name?")
quest = raw_input("What is your quest?")
color = raw_input("What is your favorite color?")

print "Ah, so your name is %s, your quest is %s, " \
"and your favorite color is $s." % (name, quest, color)
```

It's saying that not all arguments converted during string formatting in the last line

Comment: At the very least, you know that you are writing a python script that is giving you an error that is saying something like "Not all arguments converted during string formatting". So, you could have titled your question "What does the error message 'Not all arguments converted during string formatting' mean?" As it is, your current title is not helpful.

Answer (score 7):

You have a typo. `$s` should be `%s` in order for the string formatting to occur. Thus, you have three arguments which you're trying to fill into two parameters. Hence the error.

Alternatively, you could just use [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) here:

```
print "Ah, so your name is {}, your quest is {}, and your favorite color is {}.".format(name, quest, color)
```

Answer (score 4):

try changing

```
print "Ah, so your name is %s, your quest is %s, " \
"and your favorite color is %s." % (name, quest, color)
```

You put `$s` instead `%s` in `color is`

Answer (score 3):

you have an typo:  `$s` instead of `%s` in your formatting string